# Is what flexi_auth does with its use of its $this->auth object good practice?

Tags: authentication, php

I am looking at the authentication library Flexi_auth for CodeIgniter. To use the library you have to create a object one time in the controller before the lib is used
Like this:

```
    `$this->auth = new stdClass;`
```

They then use the object to store information as a form of sessions management. They store log in data and such as well.

They even reference it in there docs as a global variable, and it seems like they are using it in such a manner by using it to store data cross function.

Am I miss understanding what they are doing or would this be as i am seeing it, in that it is backdoor creating global variable namespace.